# Golang: panic before malloc heap initialized

Tags: go, vagrant, archlinux

I run `go build` in the `$GOPATH` of my arch Vagrant box.
But it prints out

```
 runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized
 fatal error: runtime: cannot allocate heap metadata
```

And the box is `3.10.9-1-ARCH x86_64`, memory 242M.

Why I can't build go files in the box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by not enough virtual memory

```
$ ulimit -v 242000
$ go build prog.go
runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized
fatal error: runtime: cannot allocate heap metadata
```

64bit go needs lots of [virtual memory space but not necessarily that much real memory](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/4Y-SO5QnGyY).

You could fix this by allocating more memory to the container.

You could also play with the setting of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.

You could also try allocating swap to the container (if possible).